# Regex.Replace(string, MatchEvaluator) not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I've got the following string:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
```

I need to alter it to look like the following:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("myClass", "myVersion")]
```

The simplest way to achieve this, obviously, is to use a `Regex` to capture the pieces that I want from that string, and then concatenate the results with my extra text. However I'm looking to use the `Regex.Replace()` method to make the code a bit cleaner:

```
Regex generatedCodeAttributeRegex = new Regex("\\[[?:global::|]System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute\\((\"System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator\",[\\s+]\"2.0.0.0\")\\)\\]");

inputFileContent = generatedCodeAttributeRegex.Replace(inputFileContent, delegate(Match m)
{
  return string.Format("\"{0}\", \"{1}\"",
                       this.GetType(),
                       Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
});
```

From my understanding, this should replace the captured group with the text specified in the delegate... the problem is that it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? And is it possible to achieve this with the `Regex.Replace(string, string)` overload?

Comment: Word of advice; to retain sanity, write regex (in C#) as verbatim string literals: @"some\n?regex"

Comment: When you've got embedded double quotes in the regex, @ is no longer your friend.

Comment: The occasional "" is much friendlier than the constant \ - and if it gets to complex, just put it in a static text block (resx, perhaps) - so no escaping to content with.

Comment: D'oh, never thought of doing it that way! Thanks for making my life easier!

Comment: just use \x22 and \x27 instead of ' and "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex does not match because you wrote `[?:global::|]`, which is a character range containing the characters ?, :, g, l, o, b, a, :, and |. You probably meant `(?:global::|)` which is the same as `(?:global::)?`, i.e. "global:: or nothing".

Also note that by not escaping the dots, they will match anything - not just literal dots. Though that is unlikely to cause problems.

If you fix that, it will work, but not quite as you want, since Regex.Replace replaces the whole match, not just the part in the capturing group.

Comment: That's closest to the answer I was looking for, and thanks for picking up the "global::" mistake. That's not the first time I've confused ( and [ and I'm sure it won't be the last...

Comment: You made the same mistake with `[\\s+]` -- in that case you should just remove the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The way i would do this is with a look behind `@"(?<=)"` and look ahead `@"(?=)"` like so:

```
"(?<=\[global::System\.CodeDom\.Compiler\.GeneratedCodeAttribute\()([^\)]*)(?=\)\])"
```

Then your replacement string should work as is.

Comment: Sorry, should have been a a literal:
@"(?<=\[global::System\.CodeDom\.Compiler\.GeneratedCodeAttribute\()([^\)]*)(?=\)\])"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about C# specialties, but I'd guess that the regular expression is plain wrong. The square brackets are used in a wrong way. They can only define character classes and cannot be used for capturing of subpatterns. All this assuming C# uses regular perl-style regexps.

The correct regular expression for this would be (attention, not escaped):

```
\[(global::)?System\.CodeDom\.Compiler\.GeneratedCodeAttribute\("([^"]+)", "([^"]+)"\)\]
```

My advice: go to http://regexpal.com/ to test your regular expressions first, then implement them in your code. Saves a lot of trouble.

Comment: I prefer Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) - available offline, C#-specific and generates regex code that you can paste straight into your app.